# Correct chained promise syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I trying to figure out how to correct re-write my function using promises.
The original working version is below:

```
this.accountsAPI.find(filter, function(err,result){
    if (err || 0 == result.length) {
      return res.status(400).json({error: "Can't find the account."});
    }
    var workRequest = req.query.workRequest;
    // result has some records and we assume that _id is unique, so it must have one entry in the array
    var newJob = { jobId: workRequest, acceptedById: result[0]._id, dateCreated: new Date() };
    this.jobsAPI.create( newJob, function(jobErr, jobResult) {
      if (jobErr) { return res.status(400).json({error: "Can't create a new job."}); }
      res.status(200).json({newJob});
    });
});
```

I have re-written this as:

```
return new Promise(function ( fulfill, reject) {
    this.accountsAPI.find(filter)
      .then(function (result) {
        if (0 == result.length) { return res.status(400).json({error: "Can't create a new job."}); }
        var workRequest = req.query.workRequest;
        // result has some records and we assume that _id is unique, so it must have one entry in the array
        var newJob = { workRequestId: workRequest, acceptedById: result[0]._id, dateCreated: new Date() };
        this.jobsAPI.create( newJob, function(jobErr, jobResult) {
          if (jobErr) { return res.status(400).json({error: "Can't create a new job."}); }
          res.status(200).json({newJob});
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Can't create a job.",
        errorDetail: err.message
      });
});
```

Not positive that I coded the promise version correctly. However, even if I did, there is still a chained asynchronous request, so my Promise version just makes things more complicated.

Should I use promises for such calls? Is there a way to rewrite my code elegantly?

Comment: Does `this.accountsAPI.find` return a Promise now?

Comment: No, find returns an array of accounts. It is asynchronous. Though, we are using Feathers.JS [so find is a database adapter method] and David Luecke mentioned that they are wrapping everything with Promises in the next version. Sorry for a dumb question - why is that important?

Comment: Because if it doesn't return a `Promise` it won't have a `.then()` method and you'll need to call `fulfill()` and `reject()` yourelf inside the `jobsAPI.create` callback. If it *did* (and `jobsAPI.create` returned a Promise too), you would simply have been able to to `return this.accountsAPI.find`

Comment: I still do not understand. Just to clarify, I can call .then on my newly constructed promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, wrapping everything in a `Promise` constructor doesn't automatically make it work.

You should start by [promisifying the asynchronous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) you are using on the lowest level - that is, in your case, `accountsAPI.find` and `this.jobsAPI.create`. Only for this you will need the `Promise` constructor:

```
function find(api, filter) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        api.find(filter, function(err, result) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
function create(api, newJob) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        api.create(newJob, function(err, result) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

As you see, this is a bit repetitive, you can write a helper function for this; but in case you are using a promise library that is more than an ES6 polyfill it will probably provide one already.

Now we've got two functions, `find` and `create`, that will return promises. And with those, you can rewrite your function to a simple

```
return find(this.accountsAPI, filter).then(function(result) {
    if (result.length == 0)
        throw new Error("Can't find the account.");
    return result;
}, function(err) {
    throw new Error("Can't find the account.");
}).then(function(result) {
    // result has some records and we assume that _id is unique, so it must have one entry in the array
    return create(this.jobsAPI, {
        jobId: req.query.workRequest,
        acceptedById: result[0]._id,
        dateCreated: new Date()
    }).catch(function(err) {
        throw new Error("Can't create a new job.");
    });
}.bind(this)).then(function(newJob) {
    res.status(200).json(newJob);
}, function(err) {
    res.status(400).json({error:err.message});
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I get an error, trying to compile this. My guess is probably a bracket is missing. I am sure that your example is OK fundamentally. I do fail to see how Promise version is cleaner, in this case. In fact, I am having a difficult time understanding it, whereas the async version is relatively easy to comprehend.

Comment: @MosheShmukler: Rather a brace too much :-)

Comment: @MosheShmukler: Yeah, in this case the promise version is not much better as the code has so much error handling in it - which doesn't just go away but is inherent complexity. I did flatten it though so that I'm calling `res.status(400)` only in one position

Comment: Looks good, except you have some redundant error handling here. There is no need to catch `"Can't find the account."` only to rethrow it.

Comment: @jib: One error is when the `result` is empty, the other is when `find` rejected. Not sure what you mean by "rethrow", how would you do that? I could think of `find(…).then(res => { if (!res.length) throw /*nothing*/; … }).catch(_ => { throw new Error(…); }).…`

Comment: I misread the code a bit, so you're not rethrowing the same error, but still catching errors from e.g. `find` and replacing them with another (presumably less specific) error, instead of passing out the original error. Exposition perhaps,  but could look a lot simpler without it, is all.